# Mantener el scroll horizontal de una tabla responsiva sobre mi footer

Tags: html5, css, bootstrap

Estoy usando una tabla responsiva que está entremedio de un navbar fijo a la parte superior de la pantalla, y otro fijo a la parte inferior de la misma (mi footer)

Pueden verlo [aquí](http://codepen.io/Pancreatico/pen/bgWagZ) (por visualización no he hecho un fiddle).

Si achican el width de la pantalla (a 900px por ejemplo) y luego en la tabla van hacia abajo, podrán ver el scroll horizontal al final de la tabla.

Necesito que ese scroll horizontal quede siempre visible, para eso sería óptimo **visualizarlo siempre sobre mi footer**, sin importar si estoy al principio, en medio o al final de la tabla.

He intentado lo que dicen en [este](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31009880/allow-horizontal-scrolling-on-table-with-bottom-visible-at-all-times) post, pero no me funciona por cómo es la estructura de mi página.

Gracias.

**EDIT** : El footer que ya tengo debe permanecer ahí tal como está, siempre visible en la parte inferior de la pantalla. Lo ideal sería que el scroll horizontal haga lo mismo y siempre esté sobre el footer.

Answer (score 0):

Si entendí bien creo que lo podés resolver jugando con la propiedad **z-index** de css que determina qué elementos están sobre cuales otros.

```
table {position:relative;z-index:9999}
```

Esta linea pondría la tabla por sobre el resto de las cosas. En caso de querer que el encabezado quede sobre la tabla tendrías que seguir sumando.

Comment: Esto no resuelve lo que busco, mira el edit por si tal vez se entiende mejor.

Answer (score 0):

Debes decirle tanto a tu 'nav' como a tu 'footer' que estén tanto fijos cómo que ocupen el 100% del ancho de la página, mientras que a la tabla debes darle una posición fija por encima del footer y un 'scroll' horizontal 'visible' de este modo:

```
  nav {position: absolute; top:0;width:100vw}
  footer{position: absolute;bottom:0;width:100vw}
  table{position:relative; bottom: "Altura del footer más un poco de aire"; overflow-y: scroll;}
```